# How do I migrate SQLite to Postgres for OWASP Juice Shop?

Tags: postgresql, migration, sqlite

I tried to make a .sql but it's failing.
My files here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BAs5YFPWpShzIgtd-NppL0iWZ_HywWNf?usp=sharing

I also tried using pgloader but that was even more difficult with more errors.

Please feel free to provide some advice.